# How to efficiently remove the food particles stuck in the scrubbing pad?

Tags: cleaning

Food bits get stuck in this. Simply washing it under tap doesn't help.
How to efficiently remove the stuck particles from this scrubbing pad?

**Don't have a dishwasher.**

[image]

Comment: if it is anything doughy/gluten outa luck. otherwise are we talking fatty or merely bits of veg?

Comment: @Pat You can just assume she's asking about everything and write an answer!

Comment: Don't use these sort of pads for cleaning large particles of loose food. Only for removing hard stuck stuff. Use a brush for everything else

Comment: @TFD I use this pad for iron vessels. Will the brush not scrub off the seasoning?

Comment: No, a typical nylon dish scrub brush will not damage it. These scrub pads could. They are designed to "cut in"

Comment: @TFD Can I use this brush to scrub it iron pans? http://www.colgate.co.in/app/Colgate/IN/OralCare/ToothBrushes/ZigZag.cvsp

Comment: @AnishaKaul this would be very inefficient. Brushes like these are normal for cleaning pans: http://images.containerstore.com/catalogimages/89134/RoundScrubBrush_l.jpg

Comment: @rumtscho thanks, so those brushes are safe for cleaning freshly seasoned iron pans, and that scrub pad is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the hot water tap on an extremely slow trickle to wet the pad.
Then squeeze dishwasher detergent + baking soda to work up a sud on the pad.
Then squeeze and "massage" the pad as best you could under the slow hot trickle.

My actual motivation has always been remove the stale stink from the pad. Somehow, the side effects are that the food particles are also dislodged from the pad by the suds.

This must be due to surface tension mitigation and anti-static effects of the suds (disengaging the attraction of food particles from the pad bristles) plus the washing action of the slow hot trickle. If the water is too hot, you might have to put on kitchen gloves.

Answer (score 0):

I just put a little dish detergent on the wet pad and use my fingernails to scrape it. Get it realy soapy and that does the job for me pretty quick and easy.

Comment: Avoid asking a lady to scrape things with her precious finger nails.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Well that's the kind of thing that might offend a lady more than asking her to use her nails.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on stuck fat or sugary gunk or protein

run through a warm cycle with laundry (when doing dirtiest gardening/cleaning gear)

soak in weak solution of borax (I should market the stuff)

just a few whacks on edge of sink to dislodge reluctant bits

zap in microwave while moist. (probably least effective but sooo satisfying to nuke uncooperative tools)